# Does MultiVersus progress carry on between servers/regions?

Tags: multiversus

In the "online settings" of multiversus, you can choose a region to play on.

So, for example, I selected South Africa as it's the closest to my country, I assume my online matches are played on the SA servers, with other players who also selected South Africa server.

But what I'm mostly asking for here is: does my progress (characters/perks unlocked) carry over if I decide to choose another server for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they do.
That setting is just for the matchmaking, you only change where you'd like to play online. Changing the server doesn't affect your game progress in any way, that's stored on your profile.